# Django Subdomain URL Dispatch

Tags: python, django, django-urls, subdomain

I have a Django project and I wanted to map a URL to handle subdomains. If there is a subdomain then it should call a function with the subdomain as a parameter. Is this possible? If not then what would be the best way to tell what the subdomain of a request is?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely possible - you'll need to tweak your configuration files so that subdomain requests are sent to that URL instead of the root of your app, and then you should be good to go (use `request.get_host()` to retrieve the domain you're being called at).

Comment: what tweaks should be made to get subdomain in `get_host()` function